# No Sharing tab on Windows 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, shared-directory, fileshare

I can't see the sharing tab within any drive or folder properties on Windows 2003. I've looked here:

http://forums.tweakguides.com/showthread.php?t=5771

However, there's no option to disable simple sharing in the Folder options and the services they recommend starting (Computer Browser, Network Connections, Server, and Workstation) don't do the trick. Any ideas?

Comment: I've found the solution, in my case the File Replication service also needed to be started. I also set these services to automatic.

Comment: Another note on this is that you should restart explorer for the changes to take effect.

Comment: This should probably be on ServerFault or SuperUser.

Answer (score 2):

Same problem...

I found [this](http://vvirtual.wordpress.com/2010/03/28/missing-sharing-tab-in-windows-2003-r2-sp2/) helpful blog article, that describes the solution of crizCraig:

[image]

[image]

And for me it was also necessery to restart the explorer.exe.
Kill the process with task manager and start it again:

[image]

[image]

[image]